# Drupal 8 REST Endpoint, custom Module/Block

Tags: rest, drupal-8

I use the latest Drupal 8 installation and have made a custom Module. My Module provides also a Block which will be shown belove specific paths. For example "/mypath". Belove this path i also show some Article.
Now I would like to make that path as REST Endpoint with output from the Article and the Block content. Block content also do have a form.

I have tried the module Block Layout which is almost doing what i would like to but the module is not showing my block content only.

Any hints about how could I make REST Endpoint which will output everything that i see when i call www.mywesite.com/mypath?

Thanks in advance and if there are any articles, which couldn't find feel free to point me to.

If you need further information just ask, thanks.